# Zend Framework String Equality Validator

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form

Does anyone know if there are any built-in Zend Framework validators that can validate string equality?  I'm trying to secure my form from spammers by asking a question for which I already know what the response should be.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's [Zend_Validate_Identical](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.validate.set.html#zend.validate.set.identical).